# Why iPhone X InputViewController height is like half of system keyboard size?

Tags: ios11, iphone-x, ios-keyboard-extension

I am testing custom keyboard extension in iPhone X. I just created a new project with Keyboard extension. As you see in 2 photos , custom keyboard's height is like only a half of system keyboard's height. I don't know why. Is there any way to get actual keyboard height like system keyboard height?

[Custom Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7d2z.png)

[iOS System Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Szr.png)

Comment: is problem solved ?

Comment: any luck to resolve this issue?

Comment: This is the exact problem that I am having. By setting .flexibleHeight option for auto-resizing mask for custom input view, like the documentation is saying, this does not work on any phones that have home indicator. I need help solving this issue too :(

Comment: @Miki Please try this. I think you need to set anchor point to your Keyboard's View. Add this code. [self.yourKeyboard.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor].active = YES; [self.yourKeyboard.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor].active = YES;

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment, but I've tried this and got the same result, no luck. Maybe something else is wrong in my code, right now, as a work-around, I am using the fixed height

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Write this piece of code in `viewDidAppear`.

```
CGFloat _expandedHeight = 500; //The height you want
NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint = 
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.view 
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight 
                                 relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                    toItem: nil 
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute 
                                multiplier: 0.0 
                                  constant: _expandedHeight];
[self.view addConstraint: _heightConstraint];
```

In iOS 8.0, you can adjust a custom keyboard’s height any time after its primary view initially draws on screen.